# error in activity.java for phonegap

Tags: java, android, cordova

I am just configuring my phonegap application and set to run "HelloWorld" Problem. But i cant execute it properly since it always throws me the following error.

```
Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method from DroidGap
The import com.phonegap cannot be resolve
```

And here is my Code in MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.mobile;

import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import com.phonegap.*;


public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I have created the libs folder and added the cordova-2.2.0.jar , and added to the bulid path. But Still i cant figure out the problem , kindly suggest me a solution to fix it up.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Seems like you have 2 problems:

1. `Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method from DroidGap` - try changing `protected void onCreate` to `public void onCreate`.
2. `The import com.phonegap cannot be resolve` - try removing the line `import com.phonegap.*;`

Comment: Stunning Man your great , Saved my day indeed

Comment: DroidGap cannot be resolve. please help me solving this. Please

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue:

change:

`protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

to:

`public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

This worked for me.